# Implement both generic and non-generic interfaces without duplicate members

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, interface

## Premise

Taking an `Enum` like so:

```
Public Enum Foo
    A
    B
    C
End Enum
```

I want to create a class that tracks which values of `Foo` are present in an internal `HashSet(Of Foo)` and exposes the data as an `IDictionary(Of Foo, Boolean)`. The class also needs to implement the non-generic `IDictionary` interface (it's required by my use case).

```
Public Class FooTracker
    Implements IDictionary, IDictionary(Of Foo, Boolean)

    Private foos As HashSet(Of Foo)

    ...

End Class
```

The desired behavior for a `FooTracker` where `foos` contains only `B` is that `FooTracker(Foo.A)` and `FooTracker(Foo.C)` should both return `False` while `FooTracker(Foo.B)` returns `True`.

## Problem

`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and `IDictionary` have members that should reasonably be implemented by the same `FooTracker` member, but which have different signatures. Let's take the `Item` property for example.

`IDictionary` wants `Default Public Property Item(key As Object) As Object Implements IDictionary.Item`
`IDictionary<Foo, Boolean>` wants `Default Public Property Item(key As Foo) As Boolean Implements IDictionary(Of Foo, Boolean).Item`

I don't want to have to implement two separate properties with one just calling the other, because that's a lot of useless boilerplate code. And more importantly I don't want both the generic and non-generic versions showing up as overloads.

Take a look at the standard `Dictionary(TKey, TValue)` class (not the interface). When you access the `Item` property in Visual Studio, the only option you get is the generic `Item(key as TKey)`. It doesn't show you `Item(key as Object)` event though `Dictionary(TKey, TValue)` implements the non-generic `IDictionary`. But how does it do that? How do they have just that one member implementing both `IDictionary.Item` and `IDictioanry<TKey, TValue>.Item`?

Comment: You cannot use `Foo` as constraint, but you can probably (= if it actually meets the reuirements) declare the class as `Public Class FooTracker(Of T) Implements IDictionary(Of T, Boolean)` anyway, initialize it as, e.g.,  `dim tracker = new FooTracker(of Foo) tracker.Add(Foo.B, true)`. Does it simplify the whole thing?

Comment: @Jimi I don't want to use `Foo` as a [generic *constraint*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/#generics-terminology) (if that's what you mean). I want `FooTracker` to implement the [*constructed generic type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/#generics-terminology) `IDictionary(Of Foo, Boolean)`, along with the non-generic `IDictionary`. I don't see how making `FooTracker` a generic type helps me do this.

Comment: Well, that's a Partial Closed Constructed Type. If you want to know how the Framework implements both `IDictionary` and `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, you just need to look at the source code. You'll find out something like, e.g.,: `void IDictionary.Remove(object key) { if(IsCompatibleKey(key)) { Remove((TKey)key); }`. So, as you can see, the non-generic method calls the generic method after a type check, casting the non-generic (`object`) value to the generic one.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The thing I was missing was that I didn't know you could implement an interface member as `Private`, which prevents it from being called via the implementing type, but still allows it to be called via the interface type.

For anyone who had this same problem, here's a full sample implementation using my `FooTracker` example. Note that this is an example of a fixed-size dictionary, which is why all `Add` and `Remove` methods are hidden and throw exceptions when called.

```
Public Class FooTracker
    Implements IDictionary, IDictionary(Of Foo, Boolean)

    Private foos As HashSet(Of Foo)

    Private Shared allFooValues As New ReadOnlyCollection(Of Foo)([Enum].GetValues(GetType(Foo)))

    Default Public Property Item(key As Foo) As Boolean Implements IDictionary(Of Foo, Boolean).Item
        Get
            Return foos.Contains(key)
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            If value Then
                foos.Add(key)
            Else
                foos.Remove(key)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Property IDictionary_Item(key As Object) As Object Implements IDictionary.Item
        Get
            Return Item(key)
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            Item(key) = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Keys As ICollection(Of Foo) Implements IDictionary(Of Foo, Boolean).Keys
        Get
            Return allFooValues
        End Get
    End Property

    Private ReadOnly Property IDictionary_Keys As ICollection Implements IDictionary.Keys
        Get
            Return Keys
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Values As ICollection(Of Boolean) Implements IDictionary(Of Foo, Boolean).Values
        Get
            Return allFooValues.Select(Function(F) Item(F))
        End Get
    End Property

    Private ReadOnly Property IDictionary_Values As ICollection Implements IDictionary.Values
        Get
            Return Values
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReadOnly As Boolean Implements IDictionary.IsReadOnly, ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)).IsReadOnly
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property IsFixedSize As Boolean Implements IDictionary.IsFixedSize
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub ThrowNotSupportedException()
        Throw New NotSupportedException()
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer Implements ICollection.Count, ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)).Count
        Get
            Return allFooValues.Count
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property SyncRoot As New Object Implements ICollection.SyncRoot

    Public ReadOnly Property IsSynchronized As Boolean Implements ICollection.IsSynchronized
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub Add(key As Foo, value As Boolean) Implements IDictionary(Of Foo, Boolean).Add
        ThrowNotSupportedException()
    End Sub

    Private Sub IDictionary_Add(key As Object, value As Object) Implements IDictionary.Add
        ThrowNotSupportedException()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ICollection_Add(item As KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)) Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)).Add
        ThrowNotSupportedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Clear() Implements IDictionary.Clear
        foos.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ICollection_Clear() Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)).Clear
        Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Function Remove(key As Foo) As Boolean Implements IDictionary(Of Foo, Boolean).Remove
        ThrowNotSupportedException()
    End Function

    Private Sub IDictionary_Remove(key As Object) Implements IDictionary.Remove
        ThrowNotSupportedException()
    End Sub

    Private Function ICollection_Remove(item As KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)) As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)).Remove
        ThrowNotSupportedException()
    End Function

    Public Sub CopyTo(array() As KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean), arrayIndex As Integer) Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)).CopyTo
        For i As Integer = 0 To allFooValues.Count - 1
            Dim F = allFooValues(i)
            array(arrayIndex + i) = New KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)(F, Item(F))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ICollection_CopyTo(array As Array, index As Integer) Implements ICollection.CopyTo
        CopyTo(array, index)
    End Sub

    Public Function Contains(item As KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)) As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)).Contains
        Return Me.Item(item.Key) = item.Value
    End Function

    Private Function IDictionary_Contains(key As Object) As Boolean Implements IDictionary.Contains
        Return Contains(key)
    End Function

    Public Function ContainsKey(key As Foo) As Boolean Implements IDictionary(Of Foo, Boolean).ContainsKey
        Return allFooValues.Contains(key)
    End Function

    Public Function TryGetValue(key As Foo, ByRef value As Boolean) As Boolean Implements IDictionary(Of Foo, Boolean).TryGetValue
        value = Item(key)
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As Enumerator
        Return New Enumerator(Me)
    End Function

    Private Function IDictionary_GetEnumerator() As IDictionaryEnumerator Implements IDictionary.GetEnumerator
        Return GetEnumerator()
    End Function

    Private Function IEnumerable_GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return GetEnumerator()
    End Function

    Private Function IEnumerable2_GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)) Implements IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)).GetEnumerator
        Return GetEnumerator()
    End Function

    Public Class Enumerator
        Implements IEnumerator(Of KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)), IDictionaryEnumerator

        Private tracker As FooTracker
        Private nextIndex As Integer
        Private currentItem As KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)

        Friend Sub New(tracker As FooTracker)
            Me.tracker = tracker
        End Sub

        Public Function MoveNext() As Boolean Implements IEnumerator.MoveNext
            If nextIndex < allFooValues.Count Then
                Dim F = allFooValues(nextIndex)
                _Current = New KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)(F, tracker(F))
                nextIndex += 1
                Return True
            Else
                _Current = New KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)()
                Return False
            End If
        End Function

        Public ReadOnly Property Current As KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean) Implements IEnumerator(Of KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)).Current

        Private ReadOnly Property IEnumerator_Current As Object Implements IEnumerator.Current
            Get
                Return Current
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Sub Reset() Implements IEnumerator.Reset
            nextIndex = 0
            _Current = New KeyValuePair(Of Foo, Boolean)()
        End Sub

        Public ReadOnly Property Key As Object Implements IDictionaryEnumerator.Key
            Get
                Return Current.Key
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property Value As Object Implements IDictionaryEnumerator.Value
            Get
                Return Current.Value
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property Entry As DictionaryEntry Implements IDictionaryEnumerator.Entry
            Get
                Return New DictionaryEntry(Current.Key, Current.Value)
            End Get
        End Property

        Private Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        End Sub
    End Class

End Class
```

If you declare a varaible of type `FooTracker`, only the generic `Item` property is accessable. But you can cast `FooTracker` to `IDictionary`, which allows you to access the non-generic `Item` property.

Comment: For the record, this is the VB equivalent of what's called an explicit interface implementation in C#.

Comment: @jmcilhinney True. The problem is the term doesn't really translate well to VB.NET, since *all* interface implementations are explicit in that language. That's probably why I wasn't able to find the answer right away, because "explicit interface implementation" just sounds like normal practice for VB.NET and doesn't really imply hiding interface members.